# Identify build type of a folder

Tags: shell, maven, gradle

I have a set of folders in different locations.
To automate the process of daily updates and build, I am writing a simple shell script that iterates over the set of folders and for each folder, it will detect if the folder is a gradle build type or maven build type or ANT build type.

Depending on the build type of the folder it will invoke

```
gradle clean build
```

OR

```
maven install
```

from with in the shell script.

Is there a sure fire way to detect if a folder contains gradle build or maven build semantics?

Say like; if the folder contains a pom.xml it must be a Maven build.

I do understand that one can choose to have a different file name other than pom.xml.

Here is what I have

```
if [["$FOLDER_BUILD_TYPE" == "GRADLE"]]; then
    cd FOLDER_TO_RUN_BUILD_COMMAND
    echo -e "\t\t\t\t ${GREEN} Running 'gradle build' in $FOLDER_TO_RUN_BUILD_COMMAND  ${RESET}"
    gradle build | indent
elif [["$FOLDER_BUILD_TYPE" == "MAVEN"]]; then
    cd FOLDER_TO_RUN_BUILD_COMMAND
    echo -e "\t\t\t\t ${GREEN} Running 'mvn install' in $FOLDER_TO_RUN_BUILD_COMMAND  ${RESET}"
    mvn install | indent    
elif [["$FOLDER_BUILD_TYPE" == "ANT"]]; then
    cd FOLDER_TO_RUN_BUILD_COMMAND
    echo -e "\t\t\t\t ${GREEN} Running 'ant build' in $FOLDER_TO_RUN_BUILD_COMMAND  ${RESET}"
    ant build | indent
else
    echo -e "\t\t\t\t ${GREEN} Ignoring UNKNOWN build type in $FOLDER_TO_RUN_BUILD_COMMAND  ${RESET}"
fi
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb:

1. Gradle projects will have a `build.gradle` (and often `settings.gradle`)
2. Maven projects will have a `pom.xml`
3. Ant projects will have a `build.xml`

But there are problems with these assumptions including

1. All 3 allow you to specify the build file name on command line (so build file might have a different name than above)
2. I've worked on projects that have both pom.xml and build.gradle (project could build in both maven and gradle whilst transitioning from maven to gradle)
3. I've worked on Maven projects which have pom.xml and build.xml (maven calls ant)
4. Many builds require extra command line args to be passed (eg profiles and or properties)
5. Not all Gradle projects have a "build" task
6. Not all ant builds will have a "build" target

For these reasons, CI servers require you to specify the build command rather than trying to figure it out automatically. Eg Travis CI requires you to [add a .travis.yml to your repository](https://travis-ci.com/getting_started)

Comment: thanks for the answer. This is the reason I asked the question. Having said this, not all projects have a .travis.yml file. The Constraint I have is these project folders are not something I can control.

Comment: Well, if you try to guess the build command one thing I can guarantee is you'll get it wrong at least once! Possibly you'll need to maintain some config somewhere containing build commands for each project. Perhaps you can guess by default but allow an override

Comment: Got it. Thanks @lance-java